# Updating only specific records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace, sql-update, str-replace

I have a question regarding updating few of my records in a table that I'm working on.

The table employee has a column with ids (string values) as follows:

### employeeID

```
45921!bba
569874
56281!rti
56287!tri
569877

etc.
```

So some of these records are only numbers and some of them have exclamation marks followed by some letters. What I need to do is update only the records that contain ! and the letters.
So the end result will look like this:

### employeeID

```
45921
569874
56281
56287
569877
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
declare @newID nvarchar(80)
set @newID =
(
select LEFT(employee.employeeID,CHARINDEX('!',employee.employeeID)-1) as newID
from employee
where employeeID like '%!%'
)


update employee set employeeID=@newID where employeeID like '%!%';
```

I understand what the issue is and this does not work when I have more than one record that can be the newID but any pointers would be welcomed.

I attempted to use the replace function however the patter is now always the same, the only thing constant is the ! symbol so anything after that can be discarded.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean exclamation point (`!`) or question mark (`?`)?

Comment: please add the tag of the db server you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with string functions:

```
update employee
    set employeeId = left(employeeId, chardindex('?', employeeId) - 1)
    where employeeID like '%?%';
```

Comment: That worked! And now that I look at it I realize how simple it is compared to how I attempted it with declaring a variable.Thank you!